# Comparison of installed software against a baseline

Tags: windows, installation, server, patch

Typical of a Windows Server installation, our company's machines have software and patches installed via various means - e.g. Windows Installer, standalone installs, security patches deployed with ManageEngine etc.

We wish to compare remote machines to a known baseline to ensure they are all compliant.  ManageEngine can accommodate the security patches but not software installed outside of it.

I considered to write a Powershell script that invokes Get-Package and Get-Hotfix on the remote machines and compares with a list of expected patches/software.

Is anyone aware of an off-the-shelf tool that will accommodate the above?